# make permanent changes for database

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I am working on a windows desktop application using C# and MS SQL 2012. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I am using the connection string from configuration manager.

My Connection String : 
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ABC_database.mdf;Initial Catalog=ABCDProject;Integrated Security=True

I have stored some data to the database now and created the setup file. During debugging, the changes which i made to the data are not reflected to the database as i view from the server explorer.

When I searched, many suggestions stated that it could be due to the copy to output directory property. Hence I changed it as : "copy if newer"

Also if i would like to store the data permanently to the database. In case if i want to reinstall my application, all the data will be permanently saved to the database and when i reinstall the application, it will still contain all the data.

Please suggest me the proper , feasible solution.

I am using the following code :

```
private void saveUser() 
{ 
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO USERS (id, password, date, status) VALUES (@id, @password, @date,'NEW USER')", con))  
      {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date);
           con.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close(); 
      }
 }
```

Comment: How are you changing the data from your c# code? How are you making a connection to the database? ADO.net? EntityFramework?

Comment: @mariocatch I am not sure what you mean as I am not much aware about these concepts. I have attached the code i am using . Please refer.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Are you seeing any errors? Place a breakpoint in that block and step through it - make sure it's reaching it.

Comment: no there is no errors. the problem is, after debugging the saved data is lost. i dot want to lose the data. In case if i uninstall the application and re install, i need to continue from where i stopped. I dont want to feed the data again

Comment: Are you creating a new .mdf each time you run the application? Try placing the .mdf somewhere not in your bin directory, and change your connection string to the absolute .mdf path

Answer (score 0):

Try `SqlDataAdapter()` to update the record. Attach your `SqlCommand` to the `SqlAdapter.InsertCommand` property, then execute it, then call Update on the `SqlAdapter` object giving table as parameter. That should do the magic. Regards.